# C# Optimisation for xml to dictionary on multilevel node types

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, linq-to-xml

i have an xml of type :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <set1>
    <a>
      <value>False</value>
      <defaultValue>False</defaultValue>
    </a>
    <b>
      <value>False</value>
      <defaultValue>False</defaultValue>
    </b>
  </set1>
  <set2>
     <c>
      <value>False</value>
      <defaultValue>False</defaultValue>
    </c>
  </set2>
</root>
```

now i try to convert it into dictionary using the code below :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace testxml
{
    struct ConfigFileElements
    {
        public string value;
        public string defaultValue;
    }
    class xmltestread
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ConfigFileElements>>
            ReadConfigXml(XDocument configFile)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ConfigFileElements>>();

            if (configFile.Root != null)
            {
                foreach (var element in configFile.Root.Elements())
                {
                    var list = new Dictionary<string, ConfigFileElements>();
                    foreach (var child in element.Elements())
                    {
                        var elementvalues = new ConfigFileElements();
                        foreach (var node in child.Elements())
                        {
                            if (node.Name.ToString().Equals("value"))
                            {
                                elementvalues.value = node.Value;
                            }
                            else if (node.Name.ToString().Equals("defaultValue"))
                            {
                                elementvalues.defaultValue = node.Value;
                            }
                        }
                        list.Add(child.Name.ToString(), elementvalues);
                    }
                    dict.Add(element.Name.ToString(), list);
                }
            }
            return dict;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is i have to iterate three loops to construct my dictionary , are there any other features in .net which makes the code legible and look good .

like linq to xml or any other type of inbuilt library in xml for doing this type of complex operations

also i would also add more tags like min/max value and these would add couple of other if else statements to the existing conditions present , which is another constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a little bit by using `Xml.Linq` and local function to parse every `set` item and get child xml elements by name

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ConfigFileElements>>();
foreach (var set in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    dict.Add(set.Name.ToString(), ParseSet(set));
}

Dictionary<string, ConfigFileElements> ParseSet(XElement set)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, ConfigFileElements>();
    foreach (var element in set.Elements())
    {
        var config = new ConfigFileElements()
        {
            value = element.Elements(nameof(ConfigFileElements.value)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
            //parse min/max on the same way
            defaultValue = element.Elements(nameof(ConfigFileElements.defaultvalue))?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value
        };

        dict.Add(element.Name.ToString(), config);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: looks good , but let say if i add max value and min value , like below , so in that case i will have more nodes ---
    <b>
      <value>False</value>
      <max>False</max>
      <min>False</min>
      <defaultValue>False</defaultValue>
    </b>

Comment: i think i should use element.NextNode ?

Comment: @KeshavRaghav You can use `element.Elements("value")?.FirstOrDefault()` to get a child element by any name and then get its value, I've updated an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleAppliation157
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = doc.Root.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName.ToUpper(), y => y.Elements().SelectMany(a => 
                    a.Elements().Select(b => new List<string> { a.Name.LocalName, b.Name.LocalName, (string)b })).ToList()).ToList()
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```